# svnX for mac os x connection issues

Tags: macos, max, osx-elcapitan, svnx

I've the svnX on Mac os X el capitan.
Now I've setting my repository url, id and password.
When I try to connect to repository I've this issue

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.myserver.com'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted
```

Any suggestion?

[image]